# can't open file with vmware workstation

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, vmware-workstation

I have a problem. I had file copy with `veeam` of my virtual machine on `ESXi server`, to my local hard disk.

I'd like to open it with vmware workstation 8, but I get message:

> The disk ...Debian.vmdk has internal consistency that were most likely caused by a host crush or host power failure.

I'd like to know how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I would attempt to repair the .vmdk. Here is a guide from [VMWARE o](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1023856)n how to do this.'

Here is the important snippet;

> Workstation
>
> **Linux**
>
> To begin using the virtual disk repair utility from Workstation 7.0.1:
>   Download and unzip the attached 1023856-vdiskmanager-linux-7.0.1.zip file.
>   Expand the compressed file, and rename it to vmware-vdiskmanager .
>   Copy the vmware-vdiskmanager file to /usr/bin.
>   Shut down any virtual machines that are running and quit Workstation.
>   Restart your computer.
>   Manually repair your virtual disk using the utility you just downloaded:
>
> Open a command prompt. For more information, see Opening a command or shell prompt (1003892).
>   Run this command:
>
> /usr/bin/vmware-vdiskmanager -R
>
> Where  is the virtual disk that appeared in the error message.
>
> **Windows**
>
> To begin using the virtual disk repair utility from Workstation 7.0.1:
>
> Download and unzip the attached 1023856-vdiskmanager-windows-7.0.1.zip file.
>   Expand the compressed file, and rename it to vmware-vdiskmanager. exe.
>   Copy the vmware-vdiskmanager. exe file to C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Workstation. For 64-bit operating systems, the path is C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation.
>   Shut down any virtual machines that are running and quit Workstation.
>   Restart Windows.
>   Manually repair your virtual disk using the utility you just downloaded:
>
> Open a command prompt. For more information, see Opening a command or shell prompt (1003892).
>   Enter this command:
>
> vmware-vdiskmanager -R
>
> Where  is the virtual disk that appeared in the error message.
>
> Note: The path was probably set correctly by the Workstation installation, but you might have to change to the directory where you installed Virtual Disk Manager (in step 3).

Comment: I've tried, the same is in here, http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1023856, but it is still the same. I don't understand, is required to folder with VM in it, to be in C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation ?

Answer (score 1):

Vmware workstation does not read vsphere .vmdk's. You need to use vmwares free tool to convert it into workstation format.

http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/

Comment: As Rob said, using vmWare Converter is the proper way to move VMs between ESXi and Workstation.